R foreach does not improve speed
I am trying to use foreach to parallelize some matrix calculations. However, I found it gives similar performance to apply and for loop, despite I used 10 cores.
library(microbenchmark)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)


mat = matrix(rnorm(3000 * 3000), 3000) # 3000 X 3000
g = rnorm(3000) # 3000 

# use 10 cores
cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)
microbenchmark(
  # multi-core with foreach 
  foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = c) %dopar% {t(g) %*% mat %*% g},
  
  # sapply 
  sapply(1:100, function(i){t(g) %*% mat %*% g}), 
  
  # for loop 
  for(i in 1:100){t(g) %*% mat %*% g},
  
  times = 20)
stopCluster(cl)


On the other hand, if I use a different function (Sys.sleep()), foreach indeed can be ~10X faster than apply and for loop.
cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)
microbenchmark(
  # multi-core with foreach 
  foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = c) %dopar% {Sys.sleep(0.01) },
  
  # sapply 
  sapply(1:100, function(i){Sys.sleep(0.01)}), 
  
  # for loop 
  for(i in 1:100){Sys.sleep(0.01)},
  
  times = 20)
stopCluster(cl)


What is the reason, and how can I improve the performance for matrix calculation?

Try a larger matrix.  I suspect the time to perform the matrix multiplication is on par with the overhead associated with setting up and handling the parallel tasks.  More replications and or a larger matrix may show more of a difference.

When adding a lot more cores doesn't have the expected result it can be worth trying 2 cores, 4 cores, 8 cores ... to find the sweet spot. Once you saturate available memory bandwidth the extra cores generate more heat but don't get you the answer any faster and in some cases might even slow it down. My 8 core CPU runs fastest on chess problems when limited to 6 cores - and hottest with all 8 cores flat out.

As you are trying to optimize R be sure you are running an optimized BLAS like OpenBLAS. More info at https://csantill.github.io/RPerformanceWBLAS/

@Dave2e proposed that I should increase the number of iterations. Indeed, if I have
cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)
microbenchmark(
  # multi-core with foreach 
  foreach(i = 1:3000, .combine = c) %dopar% {t(g) %*% mat %*% g},
  
  # sapply 
  sapply(1:3000, function(i){t(g) %*% mat %*% g}), 
  
  # for loop 
  for(i in 1:3000){t(g) %*% mat %*% g},
  
  times = 5)
stopCluster(cl)

Then foreach uses 5s, compare to 32s for apply and loop
